# Calculated sum from sub total in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5, ef-database-first

I'm using Entity Framework database-first and I'm wondering if anyone has a good strategy on dealing with summed data from a child table?

Our DBA doesn't want the calculated data denormalized in the table, so I'm looking for a way to automatically do it with Entity Framework.

My current solution is to have a partial class that contains a column SumScore.  This assumes the child table is included when I query and it returns a something like this: Scores->Sum(s => s.Score).

This however is not performing well at all for obvious reasons.

Comment: Does the score change frequently? Or could you cache the results for a while?

Comment: In memory caching for this data is not optional.

Comment: Any chance you could do this on the client?